# close() in __del__function leads to an LookupError

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

If I close my xlsxwriter workbook in the `__del__` function I get an error.

> Exception LookupError: 'unknown encoding: utf-8' in del of <**main**.SignalGlossaryHandler instance at 0x025AAF30>> ignored

I don't understand why. If I do an del ClassInstance it works fine. If I change the `__del__` into an `__exit__` also.

```
class SignalHandler:
       __workbook=None
  def __init__(self,SignalGlossaryPathStr):
    """
    Constructor
    """
    # Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
    self.__workbook  = xlsxwriter.Workbook(SignalGlossaryPathStr)
    self.__worksheet = self.__workbook.add_worksheet(self.__MAINSHEET_STR)
    # add header 
    self.__worksheet.write_row(0, 0, self.__Column_header_Tuple)
    #self.addModule2SignalGlossary("TestModule")


  def __del__(self):
    self.__workbook.close()
```

Comment: Does `self.__workbook.close() ` work outside the destructor?

Comment: @Kay Yes it does, if I put it into the end of the init function it works very well.

Comment: Does the error only happen when the program finishes, or also if you use `del some_instance; gc.collect()` in the normal lifetime of the program?

Comment: I saw them. :-) Please try `x = SignalHandler(...)`; `del x`; `for i in range(5): gc.collect()`. Does the error also occur?

Comment: @Kay that worked also fine

Comment: it could be depend on when the instance trying to be destroyed. As result, here could be situation when workbook.close() trying to use some objects/function, which is not currently available.

Comment: Seems like the UTF-8 codec was already unloaded when `SignalHandler.__del__` gets called (that's odd). Try to store `__utf = codecs.lookup('utf-8')` in the class definition.

Comment: XlsxWriter has a circular dependency and requires an explicit `close()`. If you call `del()` on your class it should work but if you are relying on the garbage collector it won't. Also, from the error message I'd guess that you don't have the latest version of the module. If not can you upgrade to the latest  version. You will still get an error (due to the previous reason) but at least it should be the same for anyone else looking at it. The utf-8 error is a red herring.

Comment: Also, taking a step back. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @jmcnamara I want to have an class with one methode. This Method is to add data to the xlsx file.